# Ionic AngularJS redirect if already authenticated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app that uses ng-token-auth. It uses 2 ng-token-auth configs for 2 sets of users with different authentication apis.

app.js

```
  $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'templates/home/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .state('employee', {
      url: "/employee",
      templateUrl: "templates/employee.html",
      controller: 'EmployeeCtrl'
    })
    .state('employer', {
      url: "/employer",
      templateUrl: "templates/employer.html",
      controller: 'EmployerCtrl'
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

HomeCtrl

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){});
```

I currently put the authentication checking in a $ionicView.beforeEnter but it flashes the home screen and then redirects to the correct page. Is there a better place to put this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use "resolve" from the state-provider..

edit => employer-state to home-state

```
.state('home', {
  url: "/home",
  templateUrl: "templates/home/home.html",
  controller: 'HomeCtrl',
  resolve: { 
          //check if user is remembered & redirect to next state
  }
})
```

Comment: which would be my default state for $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home') since I have both employee and employers?

Comment: if I understand your app correct you should first load the home-state, where you can chose with the resolve whether you should redirect to the employee or the employer state.